# Most nucleophilic oxygen base

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

What is the most nucleophilic known monoanionic oxygen base? I am thinking hydroperoxide ion or perhaps an alkylperoxy anion. But perhaps there is something I am missing.